# Google App Engine: Add local config files to deployed app

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am operating a multi tenant Node app in Google App Engine. This app initially makes an HTTP request to get the tenant's configuration from the backend. This delays the startup time until the request is resolved.

To speed up the process I want to avoid this request and instead store the configuration as JSON somewhere so that it is quickly accessible by the app without needing to ask the backend or building custom bundles of the Node app. These files need to be updated whenever the configuration changes (which happens only once a month or so).

What is the best way in Google App Engine to do this? Putting the different configurations in JSON files in a Storage Bucket seems to have the same HTTP-request. Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can keep the file in Google Cloud Storage and load it in first request and then keep the configuration in cache (memorystore).

In this way, you can modify the configuration without deployment of the app.

Comment: This would still require an HTTP request initially, correct? As opposed to a local file that would be nearly instantly available.